# azure analysis service processing using azure data factory custom activity without azure batch

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have .Net dll for processing Azure Analysis Service. It's working fine in .Net.
now I want to run same dll using Azure Data Factory custom activity without Azure Batch.

What approach can I use?

using Hdinsight i got error

FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 2
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

17/08/05 11:31:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1501755343944_0172_m_000000_3, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 2
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

17/08/05 11:31:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1501755343944_0172_m_000000_4, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 2
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

17/08/05 11:31:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1501755343944_0172_m_000000_5, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 2
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild

Answer (score 0):

Currently custom .Net activities can only be executed on Azure Batch and Azure HDInsight. Since you don't want to use first option, HDInsight is the only way.

Basically, you need create HDInsight service and describe it as linked service for your custom .Net activity pipeline.

See [Use Custom .Net activity with HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities#use-hdinsight-compute-service).

Comment: hi i have a dll classlibery1 with namespace  classlibery1  and i have class1 with one methode when i call in my program it's faill

Comment: Can you upload how i create a dll in c# that i consume in Custom .net Activity

Comment: hi, any solution for this, i want run using hindsight but it fail

Comment: @user3843858 please, post it in separate question, provide your code and error message

Comment: for windows base on demand i got error The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Any body from Microsoft can provide input whether HD-insight  ( custom .Net Activity in Azure Factory pipeline ) is capable to process the Azure Analysis Services . if yes please share your inputs. Already we tried with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities